# Implementing Delete method for Repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I've found a Repository pattern implementation.
Is this implementation of a `Delete()` method for Generic Repository correct?

```
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{
    DBEntityEntry entry = this.DbContext.Entry(entity);

    if (entry != EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    else
    {
        this.DbSet.Attach(entity);
        this.DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

If entry's state is `Detached`, will it throw an error when attaching the entry to `DbSet`?

Comment: Where did you find it, what happens when you Delete something?

Comment: you dont attach and remove, you either attach or you remove it. If you use the attach strategy then you set its EntityState Deleted. If you use the remove method then you only need to use remove.

Answer (score 3):

If all of your entities has `Id`(E.g all entities inherited from `IEntity`) property Try following code:

```
public interface IEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }    
}
// T is IEntity
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{    
   var ent = this.DbContext.Set<T>().Find(entity.Id);

   if (ent != null)
   {
       this.DbContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity)
   }
}
```

If not, try following code:

```
public virtual void Delete(T entity) {

    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = this.DbContext.Entry<T>(entity);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached) {

        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    else {

        DbSet dbSet = this.DbContext.Set<T>();
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```